# What is causing ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error in this code?

Tags: java, arrays, tree, binary-tree

I am getting errors running the following code. I have provided comments to describe what is going on.

```
// Node
class TreeNode {
    char value;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
}

// Main class
public class BinaryTree {
    // Global variables
    char[] preorder;
    int i = 0;

    // Main method runs gatherOutput
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new BinaryTree().gatherOutput();
    }

    // This takes a null tree as input from the gatherOutput method
    // and whenever a 0 is encountered in the preorder character array
    // (from a string from System.in) a new external node is created with
    // a value of 0. Whenever a letter is encountered in the character
    // array, a new internal node is created with that letter as the value.
    //
    // =====ArrayOutOfBoundsException occurs somewhere here=====
    //
    public TreeNode createTree(TreeNode tree) throws IOException {
        if (preorder[i] == 0) {
            tree = new TreeNode();
            tree.value = 0;
            tree.left = tree.right = null;
            i++;                
        } else {
            tree = new TreeNode();
            tree.value = preorder[i];
            i++;
            createTree(tree.left);
            createTree(tree.right);
        }
        return tree;
    }


    // Supposed to print out contents of the created binary trees.
    // Just for testing purposes, but it's not working right now for some reason.
    public void preorderTraversal(TreeNode tree) {
        if (tree != null) {
            System.out.println(tree.value + " ");
            preorderTraversal(tree.left);
            preorderTraversal(tree.right);
        }
    }

    // Reads System.in for the Strings used in making the binary tree
    // and is supposed to make a different binary tree for every line of input
    public void gatherOutput() throws IOException {
        TreeNode tree = null;

        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in); 
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);

        preorder = reader.readLine().toCharArray();

        while (reader.readLine() != null) {
            tree = createTree(tree);
            preorderTraversal(tree);
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error whenever I have more than one line of input. For example:

> b
>   b

Stack trace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>           at btsmall.createTree(btsmall.java:22)
>       at btsmall.createTree(btsmall.java:31)
>       at btsmall.gatherOutput(btsmall.java:53)
>       at btsmall.main(btsmall.java:18)

It's occurring in the createTree method, but I can't pinpoint why. The preorderTraversal method doesn't seem to be running either even when I have only one line of input as I get no output from running the program, but I don't know why. Can anyone help me please?

Thanks.

EDIT: I made changes to the following two methods and I don't get ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error anymore.

```
public void createTree(TreeNode tree) throws IOException {
    if (i >= preorder.length) {
        i++;
    } else if (preorder[i] == '0') {
        tree = new TreeNode();
        tree.value = '0';
        tree.left = tree.right = null;
        i++;                
    } else {
        tree = new TreeNode();
        tree.value = preorder[i];
        i++;
        createTree(tree.left);
        createTree(tree.right);
    }
}

public void gatherOutput() throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in); 
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);

    String line = null;
            TreeNode tree = new TreeNode();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        preorder = line.toCharArray();
        tree = createTree(tree);
        preorderTraversal(tree);
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

However, the output from preorderTraversal prints out a single square instead of the values for all the nodes in preorder.

Comment: Run the code through a debugger and see where the exception is thrown and what the state of the variables is when that happens.

Comment: Where are you setting the size of the preorder array? They don't dynamically resize.

Comment: @Mikaveli: It's set to the size of the line read in from `System.in`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things going on here. The most prominent is that you are reading a line, and then trying to read another line immediately after, as shown below.

```
preorder = reader.readLine().toCharArray();

while (reader.readLine() != null) {
```

You just need to read the line once. For example:

```
String line = null;
while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
    preorder = line.toCharArray();
}
```

Also, your check:

```
if (preorder[i] == 0) {
```

is going to blow up when you reach the end of the line because you never check if `i` will be out the bounds of the array. I'm not sure what you *really* want to check for there.

Comment: and also, second time onwards, the actual contents of the line are unused. I wonder if @Jigglypuff thinks the array returned is updated with subsequent reads... ie toCharArray leaks a pointer, and that arrays are resizable...

Comment: Ah I see. But then how would I go about putting the character array from the readLine() into preorder without reading the line again? And why does the (preorder[i] == 0) check blow up at end of line?

Comment: Thank you. I was able to fix it except now preorderTraversal is only outputting the first character of the input. Not sure if it's because preorderTraversal is wrong, or if createTree is only storing one character.

Comment: Youre `preorderTraversal` is fine. What is happening in your `createTree` is that your condition is never being met, and it just executes the `else` block. You need to fix your condition, because checking to see if a character is zero probably isn't helping you.

Comment: Oh. I forgot to put quote marks around the 0 to check for the character 0. I added my changes with an edit.

Comment: Just one last question if you'd be willing to answer. In order to read all the nodes with a preorder traversal and output them, would I have to make a TreeNode array with each new TreeNode object created in createTree put into the array? Or is there another way? Because the preorderTraversal method I curretnly have only seems to run through once according to debugging and outputs only the first node.

Comment: Your `preorderTraversal` method is fine. When debugging, look at your tree. Is it constructed as you expect it to be?

Comment: I think it is, though I'm not quite sure. The tree object keeps getting replaced each time a new recursive call starts, so I can only see the most recent tree while debugging on Eclipse. Yet when the preorderTraversal method starts, only the first value is outputted. If I input a0c0t0, I only get output: a.

Comment: It's because youre `createTree` is returning the last node it creates. Before your while loop you should say `TreeNode tree = new TreeNode()` and then pass *that* `tree` into your `createTree`. Then, you can just have the method be `void` because you already have the root node of you tree.

Comment: Hmm strange. I tried that, but now I'm getting a square as output instead... When I debug, the end result of the tree seems to be an empty value. The previous values all disappear.

Answer (score 2):

you read an empty line, so preorder.length = 0; preorder[0] is out of bounds?

Comment: Why is the second line of input empty? Sorry I'm still learning

Answer (score 1):

You not are initializing **char[] preorder**  in the constructor of Binary Tree and then you are using `preorder = reader.readLine().toCharArray();`

to stote the char array so it does not has the size so it throws **ArrayIndexOutOfBouds**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code would go into the `else` statement first:

```
if (preorder[i] == 0) {
        tree = new TreeNode();
        tree.value = 0;
        tree.left = tree.right = null;
        i++;                
    } else {
        tree = new TreeNode();
        tree.value = preorder[i];
        i++;
        createTree(tree.left);
        createTree(tree.right);
    }
```

Then you increment `i` and you call `createTree(tree.left)` where `i` is past the array length.

That would be my guess, but as @John Topley pointed out; the debugger is your friend.